# iOS UICollectionView Lazy Images performance issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, lazy-loading, uicollectionviewcell

I have an issue with iOS `UICollectionView`. I am trying to lazy-load collection view images according to Apple example:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html.

My `UICollectionViewDataSource` is implemented:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:COLLECTION_VIEW_CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell.record)
    {
        cell.record = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

        [self downloadThumbnailForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

To download a thumbnail I am calling a private method:

```
- (void)downloadThumbnailForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.model thumbnailForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath success:^(UIImage *thumbnail)
    {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.clipboardCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:thumbnail];
    }

    failure:^(NSError *error)
    {        
        // Do thumbnail generation failure actions here!
    }];
}
```

Thumbnail generation method implemented in model is:

```
- (void)thumbnailForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath success:(void (^)(UIImage *thumbnail))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;
{
    NSError *error;

    __block UIImage *thumbnail;

    NSURL *url = [WEB_SERVICE_URL stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.item]];

    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];

    AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];

    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;

    CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,15);

    AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime timeRequested, CGImageRef image, CMTime timeActual, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error)
    {
        if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded)
        {
            thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: image];

            success(thumbnail);
        }

        else
        {
            failure(error);
        }

    };

    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(COLLECTION_VIEW_CELL_WIDTH, COLLECTION_VIEW_CELL_HEIGHT);

    generator.maximumSize = maximumSize;

    [generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:time]] completionHandler:handler];
}
```

As far as I understand, this generation process should work in background. Nevertheless, when I scroll down collection view for the first time, I run in to few seconds lasting collection view lags. For the second scroll `UICollectionViewCell`'s are not requesting for thumbnails, so there are no lags.

My question is: How to optimise this thumbnail generation process to avoid such a huge lags?

**UPDATE:**

According to comments, I have implemented loading in background:

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^
{
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
{
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];

    AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];

    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;

    CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,15);

    AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime timeRequested, CGImageRef image, CMTime timeActual, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error)
    {
        if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded)
        {
            thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: image];

            success(thumbnail);
        }

        else
        {
            failure(error);
        }

    };

    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(CLIPBOARD_COLLECTION_VIEW_CELL_WIDTH, CLIPBOARD_COLLECTION_VIEW_CELL_HEIGHT);

    generator.maximumSize = maximumSize;

    [generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:time]] completionHandler:handler];

    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
});
```

At this update there are no lags. Nevertheless, it generates only thumbnails for the last `UICollectionView` row...

@Aju suggested solution which at the first glance solved my problem. But just at the first glance. My collection view has a resize option. when I click resize button, collection view size changes, there are more thumbnails needs to beloaded and I am having a huge lag.

Comment: Is the generation made in background ?

Comment: I don't know! I think it should be. But I am not sure...

Comment: do it as background task

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html       use this link

Comment: 1. Isn't it a background task yet?
2. How to do it?

Comment: Why not use SDWebImage instead.. You can achieve image downloading from url easily using SDWebImage. Its easy to implement too.

Answer (score 1):

Or use SDWebImage for async loading of images. It is very good !

Comment: Can this library generate thumbnails for video files from URL?

Answer (score 0):

You might missed this from apple code

```
if (self.tableView.dragging == NO && self.tableView.decelerating == NO) 
{
   [self startIconDownload:appRecord forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

In Apple code when the table is not moving, the image is downloading so there will not be a lag. So you also need to detect to wether your collection view dragging.

I suggest you to use [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView), its so easy to integrate.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer! Next time I will definitely use AsyncImageView!

Comment: "there are more thumbnails loaded and I am having a huge lag...  " I belive this sentence is not completed.

Comment: it is completed. It is just my punctuation.